# Animation slow during activity transitions

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-animation

I have 3 main activities in my app so far, splash screen, menu, game.

All 3 have animation in them (splash screen is very simply animation). The problem occurs when I transition from one activity to the next (and back to the previous).

For example, user is in activity `B` which is an animated menu. They press <kbd>Start</kbd> and are taken to the game. However just before the menu activity fades out (and while it is fading out) the animation gets really choppy. Likewise, when the game first starts, the animation is very choppy for the first second or so.

I am loading/ creating the bitmaps (and other entities) in the `Surfaceview` class constructor of each activity. I am creating scaled bitmaps and initialising other required variables populating arrays etc in an `initialise()` method in the same class. (I invoke this method in `onCreate()` of the corresponding activity class).

So I'm guessing this is something to do with how/ when/ where I am loading my bitmaps.

I've used Allocation Tracker in DDMS but I can't see any problems there (nothing being created that doesn't need to be).

GC Is running when I exit and enter activities so that could be the issue.

I'm not sure how to get around this.

Is it standard practice to load all required bitmaps etc. right at the start of the app rather than loading bitmaps as required at the start of each activity? (Please note, nothing at all is being created in my game-loop and the problem is generally only when entering and exiting activities). If so when I create these in my initial (say splash screen) activity, how can I then reference them from all my other activities?

I have researched this for a long time (on this site and generally over the net) and tried to figure it out myself but I can't find a clear answer.

All of my activities follow the structure below...

```
public class OptionsActvity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displayOptionsScreen = new OptionsScreen(this);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(displayOptionsScreen);
        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();   
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = d.getWidth();
        int height = d.getHeight();
        myApp MyAppSettings = (MyApp) getApplicationContext();   
        displayOptionsScreen.initialise(width, height);
    }
}

public class OptionScreen extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {    

    // set up / declare variables here
}

public OptionsScreen(Context context){
    // Create bitmaps etc here
}

public void initialise(int w, int h) {
    // Create scaled bitmaps here
    // Initialise other values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create your Bitmaps on the main thread. Push them to the background or do it once everything else is done.

Comment: Thanks @alex, could you elaborate? I have 2 threads, one for UI and one for rendering / updating logic. Do you mean to load everything on the draw / logic thread? I'm not sure if that's what you mean but tried it and unfortunately it didn't make any difference. Also with your second option (do it when everything else is done) - the problem is that there is never a pause in animation, I'm moving from one animated activity to another - could you expand on that idea? Thanks again